# An outgoing migration in the "here" tab of the migration page

Tags: support, migration, 10k-tools

Looking at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools?s=1&tab=migrated&daterange= (or at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/here, I can't understand why there are two URLs for that page), one of the migrations is an outgoing one, despite what this page is supposed to show - unless I don't properly understand what "here" means in this context:

> [image: migration page]

All other migrations listed in that page are indeed *into* gaming, and all migrations listed in the "away" page are *out* of gaming.

By the way this isn't easy to spot because the left and right arrows *really* scan the same :(

Answer (score 3):

This is a consequence of the issue [I've requested addressing over here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89269/multi-migrations-list-the-destination-rather-than-the-departure-on-the-incoming-m), though that was reported back before we had those fancy arrow UI elements we now have.

To summarize, that post *is* an incoming migration, from Super User as it were. It was consequently migrated out, and so for the page, it just notes the final status - that it is outgoing.